# How to modify pointer reference to struct member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I want to create BST in C++. When I try to assign pointer to new node - it does not change. After fucntion call it still have random value. Is it possible to do it my way?

```
struct wezel {
  int value;
  wezel *l_val;
  wezel *r_val;

  wezel(int aValue) {
    value = aValue;
    l_val = NULL;
    r_val = NULL;
  }
};

struct tree {
   wezel *root;

   tree(wezel *aNode) {
     root = aNode;
   }
};

void addNode(int aValue, wezel aNode) {
   if(aValue < aNode.value) {
      if(aNode.l_val == NULL) {
            wezel pt = wezel(aValue);
            wezel *point = &pt;
        aNode.l_val = point; //do not work
      } else {
        return addNode(aValue, *aNode.l_val);
      }
   } else if(aValue > aNode.value) {
      if(aNode.r_val == NULL) {
            wezel pt = wezel(aValue);
            wezel *point = &pt;
        aNode.r_val = point; //do not work
      } else {
        return addNode(aValue, *aNode.r_val);
      }
   }
```

};

Comment: `point` points to `pt` but `pt` doesn't exist after the `if` block ends. `l_val` now points to where a `wezel` used to be but isn't anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wezel pt = wezel(aValue);
wezel *point = &pt;
aNode.l_val = point;
```

Here you are creating a pt object of type wezel, which will get destroyed once it goes out of the scope, while the pointers 'point' and aNode.l_val still pointing to its address. (By the way 'point' will also get destroyed upon leaving the scope.)

Instead, you are supposed to create a new object, linked to aNode.l_val like this:

```
aNode.l_val = new wezel(aValue);
```

And don't forget to properly dispose your nodes with the respective 'delete' statements.

Comment: The output is still the same. I think its because you cannot change pointer reference inside function - I dont know how to deal with that

Comment: did you change it similarly inside your else-if block as well?

Comment: Yes. It seems you can only change value of ponter, not his reference.

Comment: Finally solved that by changing to void addNode(int aValue, wezel *aNode) - previously i was passing wezel by value